# JqGrid not function with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

is my first time in this forum, I have a problem with the jqGrid, I can not get it to work, and this problem is by about 2 days that I can not risolvere.Il problem is that if I put the code javascript within the jqGrid View: Home then everything works, but if I change my path, for example, Client / LinqGridData gives me the following error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'page' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult LinqGridData (System.String, System.String, Int32, Int32)' in 'JQueryGridWeb . Controllers.ClienteController '. To make a parameter optional its type should be either a reference type or a Nullable type. 
Parameter name: parameters
```

someone I know to give a valid response?

Thank you for everything I hope to have an answer to solve this problem

Comment: You need to show: 1) The signature of the method the grid is calling to fetch data, and 2) the URI the grid generates (find it in Firebug of Fiddler).

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for having responded, the point is that if I put in the parameters (int page e int row) 
the "?" I enter quietly into the role, and this is the first problem, the second is that by entering the function and run properly in all operations at the end of the return json gives me the value in text format and gives me a mask if I want save the file. 

I do not know the answer to the question as well because they are 2 days that I try to run jqGrid

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is basically telling you that you aren't sending the information that is required for jqGrid to function.  The problem likely lies somewhere in the code that is generating the call to load the grid data.  You say the Home view works, so what's different about that view from the route that is failing?

Code examples are helpful in cases like this...